# Call to undefined method niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf\Pdf::setOption() when using laravel snappy

Tags: php

```
<? php >
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('print-invoices', ['format' => 'A4-L']);

    $pdf->setOption('enable-javascript', true);
    $pdf->setOption('javascript-delay', 5000);
    $pdf->setOption('enable-smart-shrinking', true);
    $pdf->setOption('no-stop-slow-scripts', true);

    return $pdf->stream('details.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: Please put your question in a way which can be understood by everyone. This is not a good way to ask question on Stack overflow as no one can guess what's happening here.

Comment: Your question was marked as "requires editing" by a reviewer. Accordingly I improved the question formatting during a successing review